# Sticky in-page navigation - porting long-scroll content to a small-screen device

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu

I'm new here, so my apologies if I'm doing this wrong. My goal is to create in page navigation that operates like this: http://www.parenttoolkit.com/social-and-emotional-development/advice/relationships/how-to-let-go

As you can see, the menu is the width of the page and horizontal and when you scroll it becomes sticky so you can navigate to each section of the page very easily. The part that I'm trying to achieve that I can't figure out is that way the menu changes on mobile devices.

On smaller screens, the menu navigation nodes are stacked so you can see each one, but once you scroll, the menu transitions from being stacked to a sticky horizontal scrolling menu.

So basically this is what I'm trying to do - start with vertical navigation nodes, switch to horizontal, and side-scroll.

I'm trying to achieve this on Wordpress by integrating it into a theme and I know I need to use javascript, but I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. So far I only have the HTML and CSS that I was able to inspect on the website, but that's it. I tried to look at the javascript file, but I'm a beginner and extremely confused.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO @iamSK . Please could you share your HTML, CSS and JavaScript so we can help. If you are very new then it might be an idea to try some easier tasks first but if you are up for it then I for one am keen to help.

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks so much for your willingness to help! The code is pretty long, so I'm not sure what's the best way to share it. What do you recommend?

Comment: the best thing to do is post a minimum viable example of what you are trying to do (i.e. only a basic page with the navigation on it).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying do to? I just have a little jQuery in here in which gives the ul `.fixed-selection` when being scrolled to.

Then in my css, I have an example of two changing points (media queries) which are  max-width 800px and 600px.

In 800px, the navigation buttons are set vertically. Then in 600px, navigation buttons will be horizontally displayed and can be scrolled.

I hope this can help you.

Please resize the browser to see the changes.

```js
var stickyTop = $(".menu-container").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ( $("section").height() + $("section").offset().top - $(".menu-container").height() < windowTop
 ) {
    $(".menu-container ul").removeClass("fixed-selection");
  } else if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
    $(".menu-container ul").addClass("fixed-selection");
  } else {
    $(".menu-container ul").removeClass("fixed-selection");
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
}

header img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul.fixed-selection {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

ul.fixed-selection li {
  width: calc(100% / 10 - 30px);
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 800px) {
    ul.fixed-selection {
      display: block;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    ul.fixed-selection li {
      width: 95%;
    }
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul.fixed-selection {
       display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
    ul.fixed-selection li {
      width: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <img src="http://jhonmarkcarizon.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/themes/trainingwp/images/bg.jpg" alt="dummy"/>
</header>

<div class="menu-container">
 <ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Services</li>
   <li>Blog</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section>
  <div>
    <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


    <p>Why do we use it?

    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

    <p>Where does it come from?

    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

    <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
    <p>Where can I get some?

    There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: JM! Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. You're amazing!

Comment: @iamSK Glad I can help you. You may mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to use your code to achieve my goal, but I'm having some issues. I'm sure this is because I'm a complete noob, but I would like to understand how to make this work for my needs. The problem is I need to use this for in page navigation in a wordpress post and using "ul" impacts all of the other menus on the page. What would I need to do to make this work so that only the in page navigation menu is sticky and separate from the "section" because the "section" you created should actually be the content in the wordpress post or page. I wish I could explain it better. Do you have Twitter?

Comment: Try giving your ul a unique class name, maybe ".menu-tabs".

Comment: Also try using codepen so that I can visualize your entire code. This will be hard if I'm just imagining the structure of your website.

Comment: @iamSK Please take a look, I have updated my answer. I removed the ul tag and placed it above the section tag but wrapped it in div with the class .menu-container. Hope this edit will help you.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help me! This was extremely helpful and I really appreciate it.